# MarkLogic 5 return elements wrapped in CDATA

Tags: xml, xquery, cdata, marklogic

I'm trying to get **MarkLogic5** to return items wrapped in a **CDATA** tag but it simply refuses to. Doesn't barf, just doesn't do it. Am I barking up the wrong tree using: -

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

declare option xdmp:output "cdata-section-elements = text";

<text><![CDATA[\begin{eqnarray}
 \fl {R}_{\mathrm{sw}(e)}=\nonumber\\ \fl \biggl \{ \frac{3{L}_{1}{L}_{2}{Q}_{\mathrm{after}}}{1 2{k}_{h}{A}_{h}\Delta T({L}_{1}+{L}_{2})-({L}_{1}+{L}_{2})^{2}({Q}_{\mathrm{before}}-{Q}_{\mathrm{after}})}-1\biggr \} \nonumber\\ \times ~\frac{{L}_{1}{L}_{2}}{({L}_{1}+{L}_{2}){k}_{h}{A}_{h}}-{R}_{j}-{R}_{\mathrm{CNT}},
            \end{eqnarray} ]]>
</text>
```

Simply returns without the **CDATA** tag which is contrary to all documentation I can find.
I've tried returning the content several ways, e.g., `xdmp:quote` but as I need to parse the content using **XSLT** at the other end it really needs to be wrapped in a **CDATA** element.

The content is normally deeply nested but I've simplified here for ease.

Any clues?

*Update*

As per the answers from Ron and David it was actually adding the **CDATA**, it was only my various **IDEs**, including *qconsole* and *eclipse*, hiding it from me for convenience.

That said, the reason I was trying to ensure those elements were wrapped in **CDATA** is because it's part of a larger **XML** document embedded within another and **JAXB** was choking on this particular content as well as custom processing instructions such as `<?THING content ?>`. This was just an attempt to fool **JAXB** into treating it purely as a String.

Comment: How are you running that query? If you run it in cq or qconsole, those tools will use their own serialization settings. The settings will not output CDATA, but the XML will be exactly equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mike suggested, it appears to be the rendering in the browser with QC that is causing the CDATA to disappear.  I changed the sample XQuery to this:

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

declare option xdmp:output "cdata-section-elements = text";

xdmp:save ("/tmp/testfoo.xml", 
<text><![CDATA[\begin{eqnarray}
 \fl {R}_{\mathrm{sw}(e)}=\nonumber\\ \fl \biggl \{ \frac{3{L}_{1}{L}_{2}{Q}_{\mathrm{after}}}{1 2{k}_{h}{A}_{h}\Delta T({L}_{1}+{L}_{2})-({L}_{1}+{L}_{2})^{2}({Q}_{\mathrm{before}}-{Q}_{\mathrm{after}})}-1\biggr \} \nonumber\\ \times ~\frac{{L}_{1}{L}_{2}}{({L}_{1}+{L}_{2}){k}_{h}{A}_{h}}-{R}_{j}-{R}_{\mathrm{CNT}},
        \end{eqnarray} ]]>
</text>
)
```

Looking at the file on disk, it looks like this:

```
<text><![CDATA[\begin{eqnarray}^
 \fl {R}_{\mathrm{sw}(e)}=\nonumber\\ \fl \biggl \{ \frac{3{L}_{1}{L}_{2}{Q}_{\mathrm{after}}}{1 2{k}_{h}{A}_{h}\Delta T({L}_{1}+{L}_{2})-({L}_{1}+{L}_{2})^{2}({Q}_{\mathrm{before}}-{Q}_{\mathrm{after}})}-1\biggr \} \nonumber\\ \times ~\frac{{L}_{1}{L}_{2}}{({L}_{1}+{L}_{2}){k}_{h}{A}_{h}}-{R}_{j}-{R}_{\mathrm{CNT}},^M
        \end{eqnarray}
]]></text>
```

When QC handles the XML resulting from your query, the CDATA is eliminated because it's never kept internally by MarkLogic.    So it's no longer there when QC serializes its output to your browser.

Answer (score 4):

Curious could you refer to any of the "All documentation I can find" which says MarkLogic will output CDATA nodes ?."

In any case why do you need CDATA sections ? The text will be encoded properly and parsable by XSLT without CDATA.  There is no technical reason CDATA is *ever* needed in XML, its there solely for the purposes of human editing to make it easier to not have to encode every invalid charactor individaully.

If you remove the CDATA markers from your sample it will work fine without them.

-David

Comment: The sample contains curly braces, so in fact it should behave differently with or without CDATA wrapping. Actually it should become invalid when removing CDATA, because the braced stuff hardly forms a valid embedded expression. Unless the braces are doubled, or replaced by entities, of course.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you may have found a MarkLogic bug.  In the [output section of the XSLT spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#output) it describes the serialization behavior you want.  And it appears that MarkLogic claims to support this functionality, though the only reference that I could find with Google or searching ML's online docs was a page relating to appserver configuration at http://docs.marklogic.com/5.0/admin-help/output-options.

On that page in the section about `output-cdata-section-localname` it says

> This corresponds to the "cdata-section-elements" option of both the
>   XSLT xsl:output instruction and the MarkLogic XQuery xdmp:output
>   prolog statement.

You might try configuring the app server (in the `Output Options` section) to output `<text>` as CDATA and see if it works.  Unfortunately you can only setup one QName there.

It's possible the format of the xdmp:output option is not correct.  In XSLT it expects the QName list to be quoted, but when I tried adding internal quotes it didn't like that.  It seems to be parsing ok, as if it understands it.

As David pointed out, CDATA is really just an escaping syntax.  The serialized XML you're getting out is valid, well-formed XML.  Is your XSLT processor choking on it?  The contained curly braces would only be a problem if you're concatenating the XML into an XQuery program or something similar.  If you're treating it as POX (Plain Old XML) it should be fine.

Comment: The original query outputs CDATA for me. Are you trying to make it work through cq or qconsole? The serialization options have to be at the outer query level, and everything in cq or qconsole is nested in an `xdmp:eval`.

Comment: Yeah, that could be it.  Try using xdmp:save() to send the result to a file and then look at that file with a text editor.